# Facebook API - Post to page

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to figure out how to post to my Facebook page automatically from my website.  I have a custom CMS written in PHP that I use with my website, and I have already created the Facebook App and set up the necessary App ID and App Secret.  I have PHP code written that when I create a page in my CMS, it will take the Page Title and a blurb of the content and create a post in my Facebook page, however because my Facebook App is not live, only I can see the post.

I've tried to apply for my app to go Live, but have been denied because I do not involve a login process.  However, I don't want to log in again.  That defeats the whole point of having the extended life access token.

Is it possible to do what I am trying to do?  Or is there something I need to include in my app review request to have this approved?  Any insight would be greatly appreciated, as the response I get from Facebook is rather generic and unhelpful.

Thank you!

Comment: Even extended page tokens are now valid for up to 60 days only, according to docs, so you will need to get a new one periodically anyway … so just implement the login flow, then you can show them that in review as well.

Comment: @misorude thank you for confirming!